# Camera Remote API : Camera + iPad + PC?

Tags: camera, sony

I'm currently studying the Development Guide given with the [Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK](https://developer.sony.com/downloads/all/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/), and what I've understood so far, is that in order to send and receive messages between a camera and a mobile device, the smartphone or tablet should be connected through Wifi to the camera, which acts as an access point.

Actually, what I'd like to do after downloading a picture on the mobile device from the camera, is to pass it to a PC so that I will be able to print it and use it for other purposes. This process should be completely transparent and automatic for the final user.

Thus, my problem is that I need the mobile device to be connected, through Wifi, to both camera and PC.

The solutions I have in mind are :

1. Make the mobile device, and the PC, connect to the camera access point, so that they can be located on the same network. 
   Is this possible? I mean, can the Sony camera handle more than one client when acting as an access point? If yes, can I have a fixed IP for mobile device and PC so that I can easily make them exchange data?
2. Use a simple wifi router and make the camera, mobile device, and PC connect to this router. 
   Without acting as an access point (i.e. simple network client), can the camera be used with the remote control function?

If you guys see any other options, I'd be glad to read them !

Thanks,
Bertrand

Comment: I really want a solution for this... I would like to connect 10 cameras to a laptop, which must be connected to the internet at the same time. But somebody decided that each camera must be a separate access-point... WTH, Sony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither of your solutions would be supported.  Only one device can be connected to the camera AP at a time, and the camera itself has to act as the access point (certain models support connecting to an access point from the camera but the Camera Remote API is not supported in this case).

If you don't need the mobile device to have access to the pictures, your best bet may be to directly connect the PC to the Camera and transfer the images using the API.  The API is REST based so can be used on any platform.

Comment: Well... I guess this should be the accepted answer. I think it's a massive functionality request and Sony should really take care of this ASAP. For devices that have only a Wifi connexion (i.e. tablets without a SIM slot), that simply means that users have to switch manually between access points in order to just take a picture using the remote API and share it on FB or Twitter! This is really disappointing... Sony cameras should simply act as network clients when using the API with the option of being an access point... Can you confirm us when Sony will add this request to its roadmap please?